# Python: Search inside dictionary for loose match

Tags: python

I have a python dictionary which looks as follows
[image: key: leftname//rightname]

The format is `{key: 'leftname // rightname)'}`

I want to ensure that each 'leftname' only appears once. If it appears again, I want to delete entire value for that key.

This is what this section of the dictionary should look like afterwards, with entries crossed out (deleted)

[image]

Notice how Ruby appears twice. This is fine, as I only need to ensure each 'Leftname' is unique. Each 'RightName' can be repeated.

I have tried to create a seperate array of names with str.split. I am not sure how to use regular expressions to filter out and delete the duplicates.
Quite frankly, I have no idea how I am going to accomplish that.

Comment: Part one of your task: bring your data into a more suitable structure than having two values in one string field.

Comment: Part two: get that data as plain text. Images make it harder.

Comment: Yeah, probably worth adding what you've done so far as well. Hard to gauge what needs to be fixed if we don't know what you've made so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
output = {}
seen = set()
for k,v in data.items():
    leftname = v.split(' // ')[0]
    if leftname not in seen:
        seen.add(leftname)
        output[k] = v
```

Where `data` is the dictionary holding your data.

Comment: Downvoted because it was wrong before you added the `seen = set()` etc as in my answer.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one working approach:

```
# simplified example
d = {1:'a // b', 2:'c // d', 3:'a // d', 4:'e // d'}

d_new = {}
seen_leftname = set()
for key, val in d.items():
    leftname = val.split(' // ')[0]
    if leftname not in seen_leftname:
        seen_leftname.add(leftname)
        d_new[key] = val

print(d_new)
{1: 'a // b', 2: 'c // d', 4: 'e // d'}
```

You can also reset the keys:

```
d_new = {}
seen_leftname = set()
key_new = 1
for val in d.values():
    leftname = val.split(' // ')[0]
    if leftname not in seen_leftname:
        seen_leftname.add(leftname)
        d_new[key_new] = val
        key_new += 1

print(d_new)
{1: 'a // b', 2: 'c // d', 3: 'e // d'}
```